# Combine multiple rows into single row SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I have the following dataset and I want the variable ‘summary’ to be transposed and created as a variable

```
Date               serNo      source      summary      OrderNo
28SEP2017    101            CO            Number       123
28SEP2017    101            CO            City              Albany
```

The output dataset should look like

```
 Date               serNo      source      Number   City
 28SEP2017    101            CO           123      Albany
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by Proc sql

```
 proc sql;
 select distinct date, serno, source, 
 max(case when summary = 'Number' then Orderno end) as Number,
 max(case when summary = 'City' then orderno end) as city
 from have
 group by date, serno, source;
```

or by proc transpose

```
 proc sort data=have ;
 by date serno source;
 run;

 proc transpose data=have out=want(drop = _name_);
 by  date serno source;
 id summary;
 var orderno;
 run;
```